# web form submit text field not clear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

i have a little problem in form submit when i click send . message send but message box not clear i am using jquery to submit the form . i just want when i click on send button my message field clear auto . how to made it?
here is my form html

```
    <form id ="messageForm" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="sender_email" id="sender_email" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="reciver_email" id="reciver_email" value="">
<input type="text" name="data" id="data"   placeholder="Message..." required=""   />
    <button id='send'>Send</button>
</form>
```

this is my jquery code

```
   $('#messageForm').submit(function(){
    return false;
});

$('#send').click(function(){

    $.post(     
        $('#messageForm').attr('action'),
        $('#messageForm :input').serializeArray(),
        function(result){
            $('#userschat').html(result);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: will you please tell me how to clear it i am new in web.

Answer (score 1):

Then you have to clear that field manually, at some point in your code that make logical sense, I suggest from within the function in the `$.post`

Also you need to use `preventDefault()` to stop the form refreshing the page

```
$('#send').click(function(e){         //<- amended
    e.preventDefault();               //<- new line
    $.post(     
        $('#messageForm').attr('action'),
        $('#messageForm :input').serializeArray(),
        function(result){
            $('#userschat').html(result);
            $('#data').val('');                        //<- new line
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: when i use it page reload

Comment: It must have been doing that before

Comment: without reload i want it clear

Comment: i am using jquery because i just dont want to reload my page

Comment: See amended answer

Comment: i check it but its not working here message field not clear

Comment: Is the `function` being executed?

Comment: Yes function executed

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this cose and it is correct:

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#messageForm').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#send').click(function(e){
      $("#messageForm")[0].reset()
    });
  });
```

Your javascript must be included in $( document ).ready and it must be completed with your logic.

Comment: yes i have use this but by using this page reload

Comment: you must add "e.preventDefault();"

Comment: $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#messageForm').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
    });

$('#send').click(function(e){ 
$("#messageForm")[0].reset()      
                 
    $.post(     
        $('#messageForm').attr('action'),
        $('#messageForm :input').serializeArray(),
        function(result){
            $('#userschat').html(result);                      
        }
    );
});
  });

Comment: i am doing like this but its not working